# Cant copy all files using cp command

Tags: java, eclipse, git-bash

While copying all the files of directory to other, out of 7 files I am able to copy only 5 files.
I have made other two files changes in eclipse. But the directory contains all those file: ScreenShot is shown below.
This is particular directory whose file I am going to copy to other:
[image]

While copying all these above seven file, I am able to get only 5 file.

The command I am using is shown below in git bash : 
[image]

That is:

```
cp -r /d/dev/git-local-repo/packs/packs-importer/build/dist/* \
      /d/dev/git-local-repo/packsTest/PACTEST/packsImporter/
```

Please help me out...

Comment: You should paste the actual commands into your post and not an image of them. The more effort you put into your question, the better chances you have of getting answers.

Comment: ok from next time i will do that @MichaelMarkidis thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could try and avoid the globbing pattern or wildcard '`*`' and [use '`.`' (dot)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62071/7490) instead:

```
cp -r /path/to/folder/. /path/to/destination
```

Comment: i tried this but it is not working. and thanks for your quick reply !

Comment: What git version are you using?

Comment: git version : git version 2.7.0.windows.1

Comment: Does the issue persist with git 2.9.0?